# What is a name for a pattern where it receives data or asks for data and returns back an object?

Tags: php, design-patterns, model-view-controller, factory, builder

**Question 1**

Is there a name for the pattern below?

```
class Pattern
{
    function createObject(array $data)
    {
        $object = new Object();
        $object->setPropertyA($data['A']);
        $object->setPropertyB($data['B']);
        $object->setPropertyC($data['C']);

        return $object;
    }
}
```

**Question 2**

Is there a name for the above pattern if it is altered to where `$data` is acquired inside the method?  Specifically code below:

```
class Pattern2
{
    function createObject()
    {
        $data = $this->service->acquireData();

        $object = new Object();
        $object->setPropertyA($data['A']);
        $object->setPropertyB($data['B']);
        $object->setPropertyC($data['C']);

        return $object;
    }
}
```

**What's the purpose?**

My purpose is to seek out a pattern that acquires data from *somewhere* and returns a ready-to-use single object.  To differentiate from the factory method, my purpose is not to decide at run time which polymorphic object to create, but to return a ready to use, populated with data, known single object.  I want to know what it is called to help me do better research on the pattern and similar patterns and on how they are used.

Comment: Sounds like a pretty simple request/response; not really any specific "design pattern"

Comment: Thanks.  Well, what if I move the data compilation code into the `createObject` method itself, will that make a difference?  For example, there may be some mild logic if/then/else branching, and data assembly from various sources (GET, POST, DB, Cookies, SESSION, etc).  Will that change the nature of the "Pattern"?

Comment: you might look at datamappers