# When using SOC & SRP should I be concerned about too much parameter passing between code blocks?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, parameter-passing, separation-of-concerns, single-responsibility-principle

How far do I break down individual tasks within a typical scenario of "Web application reacts to user input"?

For example, in the case below, say a scenario is "User submits a form, causing user data to be turned into an Object (technical detail) and then saved into the database" .

I am using various services to get, filter, object-ify, and save data.  Specifically, for example, in my `$domainObject = ...` line below solely copies data from array into an object (similar to this [What is a name for a pattern where it receives data or asks for data and returns back an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37007976/what-is-a-name-for-a-pattern-where-it-receives-data-or-asks-for-data-and-returns))

I am asking, if by continuing to separate individual concerns I come across, into various classes, services, and methods, am I making things harder for myself or future maintainers in the long run?

```
class Controller
{
    //saves a domain object acquired from an HTML form & other sources
    function saveAction()
    {
        // acquire data from GET, POST, COOKIE, SESSION, database, et
        $inputData = $this->inputService->acquireData();

        // clean data
        $filteredData = $this->filterService->filter($inputData);

        // marshall data into an object
        $domainObject = $this->objectService->createObject($filteredData);

        //save object into a database
        $id = $this->repository->save($domainObject);

        // Send $id to View
        return new ViewModel(array(
            'id' => $id
        );
    }
```

**For Clarity**

Let's call "parameter passing" as "wiring".

- So, first, my wire is `$inputData`, which I receive from `inputService`.
- I take that wire and feed it into `filterService`, which returns the
  other end of the wire called `$filteredData`.
- I take that end of wire and feed it into `objectService`.
- In return I get `$domainObject` end of the wire.
- I take that end and feed it into `repository`, and receive back ID
- I take the `$id` end of wire and run it into my `ViewModel`, and that's the endpoint.

^^^^ The above is all the wiring that I do and that needs to happen when I use Separation of Concern to separate my code into various code constructs of `inputService, filterService, objectService, repository, ViewModel`.

The wiring connects them together.

I can "cheat" and merge some code constructs together to minimize on passing the wire.  (minimize passing the parameters everywhere).

And that is what my question is about.

**Question**

Is wiring up of the individual code constructs (parameter passing between various services) a good thing?  Should I do more?  Should I do less?  Is there a technique I'm not aware of that makes this a non-issue?

Comment: Perhaps you could ask on CodeReview, it's a good place to get feedback on your code

Comment: This looks like a purely generic example. If you do ask a question on [codereview.se], be sure to post your real code.

Comment: Code Review suggested I go to Programmers.  If Programmers suggests I go to SO, it will create an infinite loop referrals.  Code Review is a much smaller community and in the past my questions just hang there without answer.  If I do get an answer, days or weeks later, I typically have longed moved on and answers are of no much use to me.  I much prefer SO or Programmers, for I get my questions answered there.  Code Review is a place my question go to die.

Comment: I'm a bit baffled that Code Review refused your question.  Consider asking a question on their Meta site about that.  There's certainly nothing wrong with posting your question here, but there's nothing particularly special about Stack Overflow that makes it better suited than Code Review.

Comment: This is exactly the kind of question that we on Programmers.SE want. It is more about the application architecture than about coding, so I can see why CodeReview.SE passed on it.

Comment: @Dennis Where is your Code Review question? I don't see it anywhere. Where did Code Review suggested that you go to Programmers?

Comment: @Simon, it is here:  http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/127397/save-custom-product-kit-using-web-application#comment238173_127397

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that it depends of the business logic and the domain of the problem you're trying to solve. If you see frameworks like Ruby On Rails, or Laravel, they try to use MVC to tackle common web app problems. However, these frameworks start to get fat (for example, you can find controllers or models with more than 2000 lines of code, i.e the famous User model with a lot of business logic).

This has popularized two approachs.

1. The use of microservices in different technologies instead of monolithic applications.
2. The use of OOP concepts like concerns (traits in PHP), composition, mixins for behaviors, engines for splitting logic and more.

So I would say that if you have a simple app, with no future intentions of making it grow with hundreds of features, a simple mvc flow with helpers can be enough. If your app is planning to grow a lot, you should consider an alternative as mentioned before.

This is a very debated topic, and there are several articles of great programmers, like [this one](https://m.signalvnoise.com/the-majestic-monolith-29166d022228#.g4kvy9y4z) from David Heinemeier Hansson. Also [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8bZh5LMaSmE) is pure gold from Sandy Metz in railsconf. And other nice resource is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33041733/microservices-vs-monolithic-architecture) question.